# In Magento 2 how can I get a container layout element from name?

Tags: magento2, magento-layout-xml

How do I get a layout container element programmatically from the name?

```
$layout->getElement('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$layout->renderElement('name');
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.